# Hide comments from certain users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using the Chrome extension [Web Override](http://weboverride.com/) for a few things and it works great.  Right now I'm trying to hide comments from certain users on Stack Overflow but it doesn't seem to be working.  I think it's the way the comments are loaded.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.comment-user:contains("DevilsAdvocate")').closest('.comment').hide();
});
```

If I simply paste `$('.comment-user:contains("DevilsAdvocate")').closest('.comment').hide();` into the console, it will hide my comments, but it does not do it when I load a page normally.

Comment: Seems to work for me

Comment: Screenshots: [inactive](http://s13.postimg.org/nbg0b55iv/Screen_Shot_2016_02_02_at_4_54_55_PM.png) - [active](http://s13.postimg.org/p1z1cmn1z/Screen_Shot_2016_02_02_at_4_55_14_PM.png)

Comment: I would think that the comments are loaded async so hiding everything at `$()` will hide the comments that exist **before** the comments are loaded.  That's why it works whenever you paste it into console.  Maybe there are some events that are fired whenever comments are loaded that you could listen for or perhaps do some aspect oriented programming around whatever function places comments.

Comment: Although, looking at the `view-source:` in chrome, some comments are already there in the initial document request.

Comment: @zero298 Yes, I also think that's the problem.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a [`MutationObserver()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

This will allow you to listen for any changes on the comments section and react them accordingly.  A rough implementation can be seen below.  You create the observer and provide it the hide functionality so that it will hide all of the pertinent comments every time there is a mutation.

Then you tell your observer to watch the comments section of posts.  I'm sure that you can write a more jquery way of doing this.  Right now it only cares about the first `.comments` section it finds.  This will listen for any child changes, attribute changes, and subtree changes as well.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    $('.comment-user:contains("DevilsAdvocate")').closest('.comment').hide();
});

observer.observe(document.querySelectorAll(".comments")[0], {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

I have no idea of the performance impacts that this has and jQuery may have its own way of watching DOM changes.  A much better way to do this would be to do aspect oriented programming with the comments JavaScript code so that you can call your hider immediately after a new comment is posted or even filter the comment there.

Alternatively, and as far as I can tell unsupportedly, listen for events that the Stack Exchange API might emit letting you know when new comments are loaded.

The issue that comes with this is that I don't believe the Stack Exchange client side JavaScript is part of any public API so any changes to it could break your code.